# How can I get the function object from a call object

Tags: r, pryr

I am trying to retrieve a function object from a call object
In this example

```
ff = function(x) {gg(x)}     
gg = function(y) {uu(y)}     
uu = function(z) {browser()} 
ff(1)
```

Say I want to get the function `ff` from `sys.calls()[[1]]` I got the below but I want the `ff` function object, how can I get it

```
Browse[1]> deparse(sys.calls()[[1]][1])
[1] "ff()"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the symbol by converting the call to a list and subsetting its first member, which is the symbol `ff`. You can then `eval` this symbol to show the function body (or use it to build a new call)

```r
Browse[1]> eval(as.list(sys.calls()[[1]])[[1]])
#> function(x) {gg(x)}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `get` after `deparse`ing

```
Browse[1]> get(deparse(as.list(sys.calls()[[1]][1])[[1]]))
#function(x) {gg(x)}
```